# Specifying in which schema an object is created

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

Is there any way in SQL server to specify in which schema that an object (e.g. a table) will be created?

Please notice I'm aware that you can do this as part of the create statement as e.g. 'create table [my_schema].[mytable]....'. This is not what I'm after because my need is to create the same table in a number if different schemas in one or more databases. This without having to manually changing the schema part of the create statement.

Comment: You can use dynamic sql for this

Comment: If a 1-part name is specified, the table will be created in the default schema for the database user. The object name must be schema-qualified to create the object in a different schema. Use dynamic SQL or a SQLCMD variable (executed with SSMS or SQLCMD) to specify the desired value at run time.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware about the dynamic SQL option but was hoping for some more straightforward option.